# Google App Engine Java Backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I've been googling for [Google App Engine Backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html) code samples but I found nothing. Does anyone know where can I find a tutorial or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What in particular are you confused about? The [backends documentation in Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html) and [in Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html)  are fairly complete, and there's nothing particularly special about writing code for backends (except as documented there): You simply define request handlers as per usual. It's just like writing a standard webapp, except without a time limit on requests (and the warmup request is guaranteed).

Comment: That link is for python backends. [This one is java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html).

Comment: I just wanted to see some code to a how a working backend. Perhaps it's not so complex compared with other handlers.

Comment: FYI, both documentations are deprecated. A good start for the new Module API is here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/